# Should I use a magneto resistor and a solenoid to dynamically change resistance?

Tags: resistors, resistance, electromagnetic

I am trying to make a resistor that can change resistance with a current value.

I was recommended to research electroresistance, so I did. What I concluded from it was that I should use extraordinary magneto resistors. From [this article](http://www.physics-and-radio-electronics.com/electronic-devices-and-circuits/passive-components/resistors/magnetoresistor.html):

> (In Giant Magneto Resistance) The resistance of the ferromagnetic material is depends on the whether the magnetization of adjacent ferromagnetic layers are aligned parallel or anti-parallel. The resistance is high for the ferromagnetic layers with anti-parallel alignment whereas the resistance is low for the ferromagnetic layers with parallel alignment.

> (In Extraordinary Magneto Resistance) The magnetic field effect of EMR (Extraordinary Magneto Resistance) is much greater than (GMR) Giant Magneto Resistance.

From these quotes, I concluded that:

1. extraordinary magneto resistors change resistance with a lot less magnetic force than giant magneto resistance do.
2. giant magneto resistance is mainly caused because of the orientation of the magnet and which way it was facing, while orientation doesn't matter for extraordinary magneto resistors.

Because I thought the extraordinary magneto resistors were a lot easier affected by a magnetic field (than other models), I was assuming I could add an inductor next to, or around (It is hard to show this in a circuit diagram, so they are just shown near each other)

I'm unsure if inductors could create a magnetic field suitable for extraordinary magneto resistors, but I used one.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Jdyw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, this is a picture showing the inductor taking the input A. As A increases, the larger the magnetic field the inductor makes. Then, since the extraordinary magneto resistor responds to a magneto field, the resistance of the resistor would increase proportionally to A.

---

Is anything I said incorrect?

Is *extraordinary* magneto resistance the best way to make a resistance vary to a current?

---

First of all, I was recently getting a lot of comments saying that my questions did not make sense, so I am going to try hard. If you notice anything, could you please explain it well in the comments?

Second, I am writing this in a style to say what I think that I know, so I was hoping someone would either correct me, or confirm what I was saying.

Comment: You can't just buy a component that exhibits EMR off the shelf, you know. Not that's specified for it, at least. The best way to make resistance vary with current is definitely going to be an indirect method, involving measuring the current and servoing a variable resistance of some kind--either a digital potentiometer, a motorized potentiometer, or a linearly-driven MOSFET. Magnetoresistance is a fascinating topic, but definitely not the route you should be going down as a beginner.

Comment: @Hearth Yeah, I found almost nothing on how to get one. Is it expensive, dangerous, or just not practical?

Comment: Just not practical, I think.

Comment: Electrical [engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering) is all about being practical. What application do you have in mind for this 'resistance that varies with current'?

Comment: I heard about digital potentiometers, and thought that (since they have hundreds of resistors for individual settings) that there must be a better way of doing it. It is mainly curiosity, and was just wondering about magnetism.

Comment: @Walter Digital potentiometers are limited to the supply voltage they require. This is due to the limitations of the transistors inside them.

Comment: @Walter - Hi, (a) This question seems to be a follow-on from [your previous one](/q/635218). Please check & be very careful not to have multiple overlapping open questions. That can annoy site members e.g. they answer question A, only to later discover question B which has superseded question A. If necessary, you can delete questions without answers which have become obsolete. (Even better to have only one open question at a time.) (b) "*I am writing this in a style to say what I think that I know*" To avoid becoming an X-Y problem, it's better to ask clearly what you actually want to know

Comment: (...) *without* saying what you believe. Otherwise you are effectively asking people to both *correct* any misunderstandings you have *and* figure out and answer what the underlying question is. Again, this can annoy people. It's too late to change this question, but in future, please ensure that your question (and all relevant context) is stated first, *without* you adding any interpretation / beliefs / guesses. Only add your thoughts later in the question text. (c) You said: "*I was recommended to research electroresistance*" Do you mean magnetoresistance? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effects you list are fundamental effects that occur when certain materials or material interfaces are subject to magnetic fields. The advantage is that this is essentially a passive effect, i.e. it can be minimized by a ridiculous amount. For example, MRAM cells use TMR or GMR junctions to encode the information and they can be scaled down to something like 10 nm in diameter and a few nm in height for the actual MRAM information volume.

Other than that, such magnetoresistance effects are primarily useful if the quantity you are after is strictly the magnetic field and you must convert that to an electrically processable quantity. I.e. hard disc read heads also use GMR/TMR junctions to transduce the magnetic information to an electric one. Compasses sometimes use AMR sensors or Hall sensors, which are also (transverse) magnetoresistance sensors for the same reason.

If, however, you are actually after the **electric** current, then the route via magnetic effects is overly impractical and complicated. If - in addition - you are not size-constrained, then consider a simple electric circuit of:

1. a shunt resistor that carries your current
2. a differential high gain amplifier that senses the shunt voltage
3. a gate (in the simplest case a transistor) that is controlled by the differential amplifier output.

That way, you can set very high dR/dI sensitivities (much higher than with the passive magnetoresistance effects), and in a reproducible and reliable and cheap way, too.

Comment: By "If - in addition - you are not size-constrained" does that mean that this solution is a large one? How small does this one possibly get?

Comment: @Walter depends on the current and power ratings of course. But the proposed electric circuit would be a few mm large at least. MR elements can be in the nm range

Comment: Were you proposing a way to detect magnetic fields? Like for a compass or magnet detector type of devide?

Comment: @Walter No. I propose a purely electrical method. Your questions suggests a magnetic detection via MR elements, so that is why I explained the relation to them, too.

Comment: So, just making sure that before check marking your answer: Is this a way of making resistance (or at least simulating it) higher with an external current? (By "simulating it", I mean altering or changing output in a way similar to how resistance does it)

Comment: @Walter in my suggestion, the changing resistance is that of the transistor. E.g. the channel resistance of a MOSFET can be controlled over ~12 orders of magnitude (i.e. 100,000,000,000,000 %) via its applied gate voltage. The gain of the differential amplifier determines, with which measured current range you invoke this change..